# Magento 2 add Product Quantity to Products in category in backend

Tags: magento2, backend, quantity

**Update: Meanwhile I found a solution and updated my code.**

I added quantity column in 'Products in category', how can I display the value of quantity for every product.

[image]

Here is my code, in app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/Block/Adminhtml/Category/Tab/Product.php

```
<?php

namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended;

class Product extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended
{
/**
 * Core registry
 *
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
 */
protected $_coreRegistry = null;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory
 */
protected $_productFactory;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
 * @param \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
    $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
    parent::__construct($context, $backendHelper, $data);
}

/**
 * @return void
 */
protected function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();
    $this->setId('catalog_category_products');
    $this->setDefaultSort('entity_id');
    $this->setUseAjax(true);
}

/**
 * @return array|null
 */
public function getCategory()
{
    return $this->_coreRegistry->registry('category');
}

/**
 * @param Column $column
 * @return $this
 */
protected function _addColumnFilterToCollection($column)
{
    // Set custom filter for in category flag
    if ($column->getId() == 'in_category') {
        $productIds = $this->_getSelectedProducts();
        if (empty($productIds)) {
            $productIds = 0;
        }
        if ($column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
            $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', ['in' => $productIds]);
        } elseif (!empty($productIds)) {
            $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', ['nin' => $productIds]);
        }
    } else {
        parent::_addColumnFilterToCollection($column);
    }
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return Grid
 */
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    if ($this->getCategory()->getId()) {
        $this->setDefaultFilter(['in_category' => 1]);
    }
    $collection = $this->_productFactory->create()->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect(
        'name'
    )->addAttributeToSelect(
        'sku'   
    )->addAttributeToSelect(
        'price'
    )->joinField(
        'position',
        'catalog_category_product',
        'position',
        'product_id=entity_id',
        'category_id=' . (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('id', 0),
        'left'
    );
    $storeId = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('store', 0);
    if ($storeId > 0) {
        $collection->addStoreFilter($storeId);
    }
    $this->setCollection($collection);

    $collection->joinField(
        'qty',
        'cataloginventory_stock_item',
        'qty',
        'product_id=entity_id',
        '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
        'left'
    );

    if ($this->getCategory()->getProductsReadonly()) {
        $productIds = $this->_getSelectedProducts();
        if (empty($productIds)) {
            $productIds = 0;
        }
        $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', ['in' => $productIds]);
    }

    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}

/**
 * @return Extended
 */
protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    if (!$this->getCategory()->getProductsReadonly()) {
        $this->addColumn(
            'in_category',
            [
                'type' => 'checkbox',
                'name' => 'in_category',
                'values' => $this->_getSelectedProducts(),
                'index' => 'entity_id',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-select col-massaction',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-select col-massaction'
            ]
        );
    }
    $this->addColumn(
        'entity_id',
        [
            'header' => __('ID'),
            'sortable' => true,
            'index' => 'entity_id',
            'header_css_class' => 'col-id',
            'column_css_class' => 'col-id'
        ]
    );
    $this->addColumn('name', ['header' => __('Name'), 'index' => 'name']);
    $this->addColumn('sku', ['header' => __('SKU'), 'index' => 'sku']);
    $this->addColumn(
        'price',
        [
            'header' => __('Price'),
            'type' => 'currency',
            'currency_code' => (string)$this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
                \Magento\Directory\Model\Currency::XML_PATH_CURRENCY_BASE,
                \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
            ),
            'index' => 'price'
        ]
    );
    $this->addColumn(
        'position',
        [
            'header' => __('Position'),
            'type' => 'number',
            'index' => 'position',
            'editable' => !$this->getCategory()->getProductsReadonly()
        ]
    );
    $this->addColumn(
        'qty',
        [
            'header' => __('Quantity'),
            'type' => 'number',
            'index' => 'qty'
        ]
    );

    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getGridUrl()
{
    return $this->getUrl('catalog/*/grid', ['_current' => true]);
}

/**
 * @return array
 */
protected function _getSelectedProducts()
{
    $products = $this->getRequest()->getPost('selected_products');
    if ($products === null) {
        $products = $this->getCategory()->getProductsPosition();
        return array_keys($products);
    }
    return $products;
}
}
```

Comment: I found the solution, updated my code.

Comment: can you provide solution please .

Comment: @RamaChandranM the code above should work, it is the Updated working version.

Comment: okey. i will check.  Please put on the answer colum. dont put question column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update: Meanwhile I found a solution and updated my code.**

```
<?php

namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended;

class Product extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended
{
/**
 * Core registry
 *
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
 */
protected $_coreRegistry = null;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory
 */
protected $_productFactory;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
 * @param \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
    $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
    parent::__construct($context, $backendHelper, $data);
}

/**
 * @return void
 */
protected function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();
    $this->setId('catalog_category_products');
    $this->setDefaultSort('entity_id');
    $this->setUseAjax(true);
}

/**
 * @return array|null
 */
public function getCategory()
{
    return $this->_coreRegistry->registry('category');
}

/**
 * @param Column $column
 * @return $this
 */
protected function _addColumnFilterToCollection($column)
{
    // Set custom filter for in category flag
    if ($column->getId() == 'in_category') {
        $productIds = $this->_getSelectedProducts();
        if (empty($productIds)) {
            $productIds = 0;
        }
        if ($column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
            $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', ['in' => $productIds]);
        } elseif (!empty($productIds)) {
            $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', ['nin' => $productIds]);
        }
    } else {
        parent::_addColumnFilterToCollection($column);
    }
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return Grid
 */
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    if ($this->getCategory()->getId()) {
        $this->setDefaultFilter(['in_category' => 1]);
    }
    $collection = $this->_productFactory->create()->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect(
        'name'
    )->addAttributeToSelect(
        'sku'   
    )->addAttributeToSelect(
        'price'
    )->joinField(
        'position',
        'catalog_category_product',
        'position',
        'product_id=entity_id',
        'category_id=' . (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('id', 0),
        'left'
    );
    $storeId = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('store', 0);
    if ($storeId > 0) {
        $collection->addStoreFilter($storeId);
    }
    $this->setCollection($collection);

    $collection->joinField(
        'qty',
        'cataloginventory_stock_item',
        'qty',
        'product_id=entity_id',
        '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
        'left'
    );

    if ($this->getCategory()->getProductsReadonly()) {
        $productIds = $this->_getSelectedProducts();
        if (empty($productIds)) {
            $productIds = 0;
        }
        $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', ['in' => $productIds]);
    }

    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}

/**
 * @return Extended
 */
protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    if (!$this->getCategory()->getProductsReadonly()) {
        $this->addColumn(
            'in_category',
            [
                'type' => 'checkbox',
                'name' => 'in_category',
                'values' => $this->_getSelectedProducts(),
                'index' => 'entity_id',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-select col-massaction',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-select col-massaction'
            ]
        );
    }
    $this->addColumn(
        'entity_id',
        [
            'header' => __('ID'),
            'sortable' => true,
            'index' => 'entity_id',
            'header_css_class' => 'col-id',
            'column_css_class' => 'col-id'
        ]
    );
    $this->addColumn('name', ['header' => __('Name'), 'index' => 'name']);
    $this->addColumn('sku', ['header' => __('SKU'), 'index' => 'sku']);
    $this->addColumn(
        'price',
        [
            'header' => __('Price'),
            'type' => 'currency',
            'currency_code' => (string)$this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
                \Magento\Directory\Model\Currency::XML_PATH_CURRENCY_BASE,
                \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
            ),
            'index' => 'price'
        ]
    );
    $this->addColumn(
        'position',
        [
            'header' => __('Position'),
            'type' => 'number',
            'index' => 'position',
            'editable' => !$this->getCategory()->getProductsReadonly()
        ]
    );
    $this->addColumn(
        'qty',
        [
            'header' => __('Quantity'),
            'type' => 'number',
            'index' => 'qty'
        ]
    );

    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getGridUrl()
{
    return $this->getUrl('catalog/*/grid', ['_current' => true]);
}

/**
 * @return array
 */
protected function _getSelectedProducts()
{
    $products = $this->getRequest()->getPost('selected_products');
    if ($products === null) {
        $products = $this->getCategory()->getProductsPosition();
        return array_keys($products);
    }
    return $products;
}
}
```